# Solved the problem. Might some cleanup and/or advise

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to display 1 outcome of 1 single custom field or attribute in the category overview, using a third party customfield extension in my J! and VM website. I got it working using the code below. As this is the first time I actually write PHP and MySQL stuff myself, I was pretty proud, but also thinking 'this can probably be done better..'

```
<?php  
//first get the customfieldid for the product where the custom id is 10
$db2 = JFactory::getDBO();
$db2->setQuery("SELECT virtuemart_customfield_id FROM #__virtuemart_product_customfields WHERE virtuemart_product_id=".$product->virtuemart_product_id." and virtuemart_custom_id=10 ;");
$db2->query();
$customFieldId = $db2->loadResult();

//make a database connection and find the field record that contains the customfield string
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT customsforall_value_id FROM #__virtuemart_product_custom_plg_customsforall WHERE virtuemart_product_id=".$product->virtuemart_product_id." and customfield_id=".$customFieldId." ;");  
$db->query();
$staatValueId = $db->loadResult();

//knowing the customsforall id with the product, saved in a $ we get the attached string
$customStaat = JFactory::getDBO();
$customStaat->setQuery("SELECT customsforall_value_name FROM #__virtuemart_custom_plg_customsforall_values WHERE virtuemart_custom_id=10 and customsforall_value_id=".$staatValueId." ;");
$customStaat->query();
$resultStaat = $customStaat->loadResult();

//display the state
echo "<span class=\"cat-staat-product\">".$resultStaat."</span>";
?>
```

Can I do this better, or clean things up?

Comment: Please state only the purpose of the code in the title.

Answer (score 1):

**Security**

You should use prepared statements for all variable data to protect against SQL injection.

The thing is, Joomla actually doesn't seem to [support prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079199/how-to-use-prepare-statemets-bind-values-in-a-query-in-joomla-3). For me, that would be a reason to think about using a different CMS, but you should at the very least follow their guidelines to [prevent SQL injection](https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Constructing_SQL_queries) (checking data type and escaping. which - when done correctly - does offer complete protection against injections).

When echoing data, you should also [protect against XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php).

**Misc**

- all your SQL keywords should be uppercase (eg `and` -> `AND`) to increase readability.
- your table and column names are too long, which makes the queries hard to read. For example, to you really need `customsforall` or `virtuemart` in them?
- you get a new DBO for each query, this doesn't seem necessary.
- you should be able to use JOIN to reduce the amount of queries you have.